# vertical space in center mode in latex

Tags: spacing

```
  \begin{center}
    \Huge{\bf\vspace{6.5cm} ABSTRACT}  
   \end{center}

    \vspace{3 cm}

    %%%%%%%% Write the abstract of your project %%%%%%%%%%%%%

Coding Theory plays an important role in modern communication systems. It is one of the most interesting parts of Mathematics and Informatics that concerned with the reliable transmission of information over communication channels. It practically deals with encoding, transmission and decoding of information in a systematic manner.

\vspace{0.3cm}
In this project report,  a new product of two polynomials is defined over
a field. It is a generalization of the ordinary product. For convenience, we call the two polynomials as outer and inner polynomials. The newly defined product then results in non-overlapping segments obtained by multiplying it with coefficients of outer
polynomials and expanding powers of the variable. It is called `Ordered Power
Product'. It has elegant algebraic properties which lead us to new algebraic structures.
```

I want some extra vertical space above the word ABSTRACT. How to do this?

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer.

Answer (score 3):

The main change you need to make is to replace `\vspace{6.5cm}` with `\vspace*{6.5cm}`.

To make the code easier to read, I'd also move the `\vspace*` directive out of the `center` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\parskip{3mm} %add some vertical whitespace between paragraphs

\begin{document}
\vspace*{6.5cm}
\begin{center}
\Huge\bfseries ABSTRACT % \Huge is a switch, i.e., it doesn't take an argument
\end{center}
\vspace{3 cm}

%%%%%%%% Write the abstract of your project %%%%%%%%%%%%%

Coding Theory plays an important role in modern communication systems. It is one of the most interesting parts of Mathematics and Informatics that concerned with the reliable transmission of information over communication channels. It practically deals with encoding, transmission and decoding of information in a systematic manner.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. i t is coming now